# How to rerender useEffect when state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

Need to update the useEffect call when I update the state. can anyone correct the code?
Currently is working like this screenshot the updated data is rendering after pre-render data.
what is needed is when I click on any filter every it renders new data.
[Check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOvvL.png)

Here is my code :

```
const PAGE_NUMBER =1;

export const SimpleInfiniteList = () => {

  const [img, setImg] = useState('')
  const [page, setPage] = useState(PAGE_NUMBER)
  const iddata = img.slice(-1)
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('top')
  const [, forceUpdate] = useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);


useEffect(() => {
  const filt = () => {

    if(filter > 0){
      filt()
      
    }

  }

}, [])
  

 

  useEffect( () => {
    forceUpdate()
   
  fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/${filter}.json?after=${ iddata.length > 0 ? iddata.map(id => `t3_${id.data.id}`): ''}&page=${page}&limit=2`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setImg([...img, ...data.data.children], 
    )
  )
}, [filter,page])



console.log(img)



const scrollToEnd = () => {
  setPage(page + 1) 
}
window.onscroll = function () {
  const bottom =  Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight
  
  if (bottom,
     Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight
    ) {
      scrollToEnd() 
      console.log('loading....')
  }
}
}
```

Comment: it will re-render it `[filter,page]`

Comment: didn't work like this its re-rendering the data after previous data not new data - check screenshot